# Cannot connect Canon DSLR 750D as webcam with ubuntu

Tags: webcam, canon

I am trying to connect Canon EOS 750D as webcam with my (Ubuntu 20.04) laptop using following steps.

https://maximevaillancourt.com/blog/canon-dslr-webcam-debian-ubuntu

and I am getting following error.

*** Error ***
Could not detect any camera
*** Error (-105: 'Unknown model') ***

May i know how can i fix such issue?

Below are images for the connection and camera (to show that i am connecting properly)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu release/version? Was there any error message when installing the required packages? Where exactly ht error you mentioned comes up? Have you tried other devices as explicitly mentioned in the tutorial? Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the camera to start diagnosing. Also look at `ls -ltr /dev`.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 platform.

Answer (score 0):

This camera is not even compatible with the official [EOS Webcam Utility](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/self-help-center/eos-webcam-utility/), from Canon for Windows and Mac.

The camera probably cannot be used as a webcam.

Comment: I just checked Canon EOS 750 D is supported http://gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php